# Huawei Bluetooth behaviour in background scanning

Tags: android, bluetooth, beacon, huawei-mobile-services

I'm currently working on an background beacon scanning service (foreground, separate process).
I found out that different producer like samsung override the default android behaviour regarding bluetooth scanning in sleep mode.

Currently I have problems with HUAWEI devices. It seems that HUAWEI stops bluetooth scanning completely when device goes to sleep mode.

I couldn't find any posts about HUAWEI bluetooth problems so far, so I'm curious about if anyone made similar experiences?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the Android Beacon Library project is tracking this issue here: https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/issues/554

Huawei Android ROMs appear to have a custom bluetooth logic that limits how many times an app can start a bluetooth scan when the screen is off.  If over some undocumented limit, scans will be blocked and no bluetooth detections can take place.